# How to call classes from model with provider class that extends ChangeNotifier?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I trying to give a specific class to user and tokens from my models below:

```
import 'dart:convert';

User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
  User({
    required this.user,
    required this.tokens,
  });

  UserClass user;
  Tokens tokens;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    user: UserClass.fromJson(json["user"]),
    tokens: Tokens.fromJson(json["tokens"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "user": user.toJson(),
    "tokens": tokens.toJson(),
  };
}

class Tokens {
  Tokens({
    required this.access,
    required this.refresh,
  });

  Access access;
  Access refresh;

  factory Tokens.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Tokens(
    access: Access.fromJson(json["access"]),
    refresh: Access.fromJson(json["refresh"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "access": access.toJson(),
    "refresh": refresh.toJson(),
  };
}

 ....
```

and I tried to set the user like this:

```
 class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User _user = User(user: user.user, tokens: tokens.tokens);

  User get user => _user;
  User get tokens => _user;

  void setUser(User user) {
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

but the user or tokens can't be accessed

I'm not really sure the way I'm trying to do is logically correct so let me know and correct me.

Comment: Does it work if you change it like this? `class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier `

Comment: @h8moss no it's the same